# jQuery: Get the first cell in the first row that has a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using this:

```
$('#' + tableID + "tr:first td:first")
```

To get my first cell, but there is potential the first cell isn't what I want. The cell I'm looking for is the first cell in the first row that has the class 'canEdit'. Any idea how to go about doing that?

Comment: Does the row or the cell have the class `canEdit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is this from my understanding

```
$('#' + tableID + " tr:first td.canEdit:first")
// gets "first cell" in the "first row" that has class edit
```

Comment: There are more than one cell with "canEdit" attached to it. This does give me the cell, but I have to add an index to grab the first.

Comment: This will get you the first cell.. within the first row with class=canEdit

Comment: do note.. that you should specify tbody as @espascarello noted in his answer.  As it will look for the first <tr> it finds..

Comment: I specified tbody after the fact, but the edited version that you put above works.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the respective class to your selector, like this:

If the row has to have the respective class:

```
$('#' + tableID + " tr.canEdit:first td:first")
```

Or if the cell has to have the class:

```
$('#' + tableID + " tr:first td.canEdit:first")
```

<sup>Also note the added space before the "tr" in the selector.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Add your class to the selector.

```
$('#' + tableID + " tr.canEdit:first td:first")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the tr. You should also limit to the tbody so it does not look in the thead or tfoot for the rows.

```
$('#' + tableID + " tbody tr.canEdit:first td:first")
```